# Java Security Setting block JavaFX 8 jnlp from running

Tags: java, security, deployment, javafx, jnlp

I developed a javaFX 8 application and i need to view it with Java Web Start. Java security settings keeps blocking my application even after Self signing it. is there a way to  resolve this issue?

Comment: *"Java security settings keeps blocking my application"*  ..Why?